# Not getting Keyboard Hide notification

Tags: objective-c, io

I am noticing that after I register for the `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` notification, I do not get the callback `keyboardDisappeared:(NSNotification*)note`

I am trying to hit the "down keyboard button" on my keyboard but nothing is firing.

This is how I register:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDisappeared:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:self];
```

And this is my callback:

```
- (void)keyboardDisappeared:(NSNotification*)note
{
    NSLog@("called");
}
```

Also this method :

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

is not getting called. But this one:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

IS getting called...

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the UITextField delegate method, textFieldShouldReturn:, and have your text field resign first responder status in that method.